Connecting semi-conductors to outside wires
I know about semi-conductors, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode .
Question is: how is a transistor or a more complex semi-conductor wired to the metal outside without accidentally creating a Schottky-diode?

By engineering an Ohmic contact instead. For various semiconductors it is still difficult.

I can see two close votes but don't understand the reason. If there is a valid reason (as, say, a duplicate or the question being really stupid) I will delete it myself. Pleas don't hide in the shadows.

In semiconductor devices, electrical metal contacts are made that are called "ohmic contacts" with a very low (linear) resistance as opposed to the Schottky contacts with a very high non-linear resistance due to the large Schottky energy barrier and large associated depletion zone. The ohmic contacts are usually achieved by a very high surface doping under the metal which creates only a very thin depletion zone associated with the energy barrier. This has only a very low resistance because the electrons (or holes) don't have to surmount the Schottky energy barrier but can easily traverse it by quantum mechanical tunneling.

You say "The ohmic contacts are usually achieved by a very high surface doping under the metal which creates only a very thin depletion zone associated with the energy barrier. " Could you explain that? Between the lines I read that the semi-conductor part is highly doped such that the contact to the wiring metal still makes a Schottky diode but with very low efficiency near to an Ohmic contact?

This is correct. When the surface of the semiconductor is very highly doped, the metal on top produces a "Schottky-type" junction with a very thin energy barrier which, due to tunneling through the barrier instead of thermionic emission over the barrier has a practically linear I-V characteristic with a very low ohmic resistance. Thus "ohmic contact".

the chip and the chip carrier are connected for example with wire bonds consisting of a thin gold wire which is thermosonically welded to contact pads on each which do not constitute schottky junctions.
